# What is the best method to generate heat from a compressed air canister?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, cfd, compressed-air

I want to convert the pressured air exiting a valve to heat. I know that a vortex tube can be used to do this, but I am wondering if I need to make modifications to the vortex tube to make it more efficient or if there is just another, more efficient, way to generate heat.

Comment: Wait a minute.  If compressed air is exiting it's container through a valve to outside atmospheric pressure, it is expanding, so it would be cooling.

Comment: To my knowledge a vortex tube is already optimized for this.  An upstream valve will cool the gas and drop the pressure so eliminate that valve if you can.  Or open the valve all the way to there is no obstruction.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it.

Comment: You have not fully fixed it.  You are not generating heat.  This is an adiabatic device.

Comment: a vortex tube does indeed generate heat. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_tube  How efficient this is I have no idea.

Comment: @agentp Maybe we disagree on generate.  Not going to argue with you.

Comment: the vortex tube was thoroughly covered in a featured question with a bounty just last month.

Comment: @nielsnielsen got a link for that?

Comment: What do you want to heat, and what options are available (such as convective transfer)?   What temperature is your pressurized source air and what temperature is the object to be heated?

Comment: my mistake, it's on the physics stack exchange.

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to use the air to drive a turbine (probably a radial turbine as they are used in turbochargers). The turbine could be connected to a generator and the generator to a resistor. You will most likely need to cool the bearing of the turbine and the generator as well, so you will generate a lot of heat.

[image]

Assuming that your pressurised air (@4500PSI=320bar) is at room-temperature, 20°C the extraction of the potential pressure energy will result in pretty low temperature at the exhaust of your process.

I used [ethermo.us](http://www.ethermo.us/) to calculate the thermodynamic states. For a ideal (efficiency=1.0) process the expansion from 320 bar and 20°C to 1 bar (ambient pressure) would result in the condensation of air, which makes everything a lot more complicated, so I expanded only to 12 bar. But even at 12 bar the exhaust air will have -160°C.

*I would appreciate if someone could cross-check those numbers and calculations!*

Step 1: Mass of compressed air in the container
Volume: $V = 1l$,
density: $\rho_\mathrm{@310bar, 20°C} = 330,33 \frac{kg}{m^3}$
Mass of air in the container, $m_\mathrm{air}=V \cdot \rho = 0,33kg$

Step 2: Specific enthalpy-difference for isentropic expansion. Both states have the same specific entropy ($5\frac{kJ}{kgK}$)
Initial state: $h_\mathrm{@310bar, 20°C} = 248,39 \frac{kJ}{kg}$
Final state: $h_\mathrm{@12bar, -160°C} = 91,86 \frac{kJ}{kg}$

Step 3: Available energy
$\Delta H = \left(h_\mathrm{@310bar, 20°C} - h_\mathrm{@12bar, -160°C} \right) \cdot m_\mathrm{air} = 51,71 kJ $

It is unlikely that a process will extract $52 kJ$ so it is likely to be less. I am afraid (given no errors) that this amount of energy will not justify the technical challenges.

---

Remark:
The working mechanism of the [vortex-tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_tube) is analytically described by Polihronov and Straatman<sup>1</sup>. The author states the following with respect to heating<sup>2</sup>:

> In conclusion: if one needs to convert the energy of pressurized gas into **heat** by using the vortex tube effect, the best approach is: remove the hot exit of the tube.(...)and drive a heat pump with it to produce heat.

[1]: Polihronov, Jeliazko G.; Straatman, Anthony G. (2012). "Thermodynamics of angular propulsion in fluids". Physical Review Letters.
[2]: Polihronov, [Heating using a vortex tube](https://www.quora.com/Heating-using-a-vortex-tube)

Comment: search "vortex tube" on the physics stack exchange for a correct explanation of how it works.

Comment: I reformulated the section and added references, thank for nudge!

Comment: @rul30. For scale, my pressured air tank is small, the size of a paintball compressed air tank (maybe around 1 Liter). 

I want to heat aluminum or copper the size of a post it note. Maybe something like 75mmx75mmx0.1mm Aluminum foil.

I want to get it to around 400 degree Celsius for as long as possible.

Like a portable heater without the flame.

Comment: Thanks @layssi for the clarification, could you please add the pressure inside the tank.

Comment: @rul39. Very sorry for the late reply. Pressure inside the tank is 4500 psi.

Comment: Thanks @layssi for the info. Sadly it seems that independently of the process you would use to convert the pressure energy, it might only be able to heat on cup of water.

Comment: @rul30. I think that if I can get a cup of water (150ml) to boiling temperature, I think it is enough for me.

Comment: @layssi. 0,15×4,179×80 = 50,148 kJ  (mass of water x heat capacity x temperature difference)...so as long as you find a process with an efficiency of 97% (50,14/51,71) it might work. Good luck, and keep us posted!

Answer (score 2):

Any engine that can run on compressed air will do this. There are quite a few, but as an example imagine a cylinder that has a bit of compressed air in it. The pressure will push on the piston doing work until it has equalized with the atmospheric pressure. Then a valve opens and perhaps a flywheel or another piston on a crankshaft pushes the piston back and vents the air out to the atmosphere, a new bit of compressed air is admitted and the cycle repeats.

In the absence of a load, the engine will convert all of the pressure energy into heat from friction in the cylinder or bearings as well as air resistance.

Answer (score 1):

Since the expanding air will try to cool it's immediate surroundings, you need isolate the expanded air supply from the area to be heated. As long as you have a heat sink, you can use an air motor to run a heat pump.

Of course, you can capture heat during the filling of the cylinder too.